# Is there a way to query for disabled and enabled sql accounts SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there a way in sql server 2005 to query for enabled and disabled accounts?

basically I wanted to see the current state of user accounts.
I mean the accounts affected by command below.

ALTER LOGIN someuser ENABLED|DISABLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select * from sys.sql_logins` gives you the information you're after.  Take a look @ the `is_disabled` column.

Comment: ...edited to move from old-style to new-style catalog tables.  `sys.server_principals` may be more appropriate if you want NT logins included as well.

Comment: In 2008R2 (and likely anything above), sys.sql_logins will only return SQL Server logins and not AD Users/Groups. There is currently no disclaimer that sys.server_principals is going to be deprecated.

Comment: `sys.sql_logins` doesn't contain `is_disabled`, but `sys.server_principals` does ... so after the edit, the answer is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You're "not supposed" to query the sys tables directly. sp_helpuser, sp_MShasdbaccess can be used as an alternative.

Comment: Really?  I thought that was what they were there for.  Well, that, and supporting MSSQL in it's day-to-day running of course.  :)